# MySQL Max is not selected the maximumn value with multiple joins

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the latest activity from some cradel to the grave reporting for our PBX.  I have the following code which gives me a great view of all the actions for each agent today:

```
 select  e.`event_id`, `event_time` as event_time, e.g_event_id,
     p.`agent_id`,
     `a_name`, `a_number`
     from `c2g`.`events`  as e
     left join `event_parties` as p on e.`g_event_id` = p.`g_event_id`
     Left join `agent` as a on p.agent_id = a.agent_id
     where p.agent_id is not null
     and p.agent_id <> 0
     order by event_time desc;
```

And the following code which should just give me the latest event for each agent:

```
 select  e.`event_id`, MAX(`event_time`) as event_time, e.g_event_id,
    p.`agent_id`,
    `a_name`, `a_number`
    from `c2g`.`events`  as e
    left join `event_parties` as p on e.`g_event_id` = p.`g_event_id`
    Left join `agent` as a on p.agent_id = a.agent_id
    where p.agent_id is not null
    and p.agent_id <> 0
    GROUP BY a_name
    order by a_name asc;
```

However I am not actually getting the latest event, I get a recent one, but there is always several newer events that are ignored.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: this is not standard sql. For better results, don't rely on mysql specific queries. All selected expressions should appear in the GROUP BY statement. Also, GROUP BY, by default, orders by ASC on the expression. Your order by statement is redundant

Comment: where is the `a_name` coming from? Which table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if works

```
select  e.`event_id`, e.`event_time`, e.g_event_id,
p.`agent_id`,
`a_name`, `a_number`
from `c2g`.`events`  as e
left join `event_parties` as p on e.`g_event_id` = p.`g_event_id`
Left join `agent` as a on p.agent_id = a.agent_id
where p.agent_id is not null
and p.agent_id <> 0
GROUP BY a_name
order by e.`event_time` DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```